# Diffusion equation with integral boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

Given the diffusion equation:

$$\dfrac{\partial\Phi(x,t)}{\partial t}=k\dfrac{\partial^2\Phi(x,t)}{\partial x^2}$$
and the condition:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\Phi(x,t)|^2dx=1,\forall t\in(-\infty,+\infty)$$
what is the method to find the solutions of the previous partial differential equation?
Thanks

Comment: Fourier transform is probably your best bet.

Comment: No solution.$\ $

Comment: @Andrew: what is the proof of your statment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose such a solution exists. Then due to the uniqueness of the Cauchy problem 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
u_t-ku_{xx}&=&0,\ t>0,\\
u|_{t=0}&=&\Phi(x,0),
\end{array}
\right.
$$
solution in $L_\infty([0,T],L_2(\mathbb R))$, $0<T<\infty$, the solution can be represented as a Poisson potential:
$$
\Phi(x,t)=\int_{\mathbb R}Z(x-y,t)\Phi(y,0)\,dy.
$$
Нere $Z(x,t)=(4\pi kt)^{-1/2}e^{-x^2/4kt}$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation.

Form there it's straightforward to check that for $t>0$ derivatives $\Phi_t(\cdot,t),\ \Phi_{xx}(\cdot,t)\in L_2(\mathbb R)$. Denote
$$
I(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi^2(x,t)\,dx.
$$
Then 
$$
I'(t)=2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi_t\Phi\, dx=2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}k\Phi_{xx}\Phi\, dx=-2k\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Phi_x^2\, dx<0.
$$
Therefore $I(t)$ cannot be a constant.